# Erro ao Ler XML com namespace no PHP

Tags: php, xml

Preciso acessar o valor das tags `numeroCNS`, `dataAtribuicao`, `etc` do seguinte arquivo *XML*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <cad:responseConsultar xmlns:cad="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/cadsus/v5r0/cadsusservice">
        <usu:UsuarioSUS xmlns:usu="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/cadsus/v5r0/usuariosus" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <usu:Cartoes>
                <usu:CNS>
                    <cns:numeroCNS xmlns:cns="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/cadsus/v5r0/cns">foo</cns:numeroCNS>
                    <cns:dataAtribuicao xmlns:cns="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/cadsus/v5r0/cns">bar</cns:dataAtribuicao>
                    <cns:tipoCartao xmlns:cns="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/cadsus/v5r0/cns">fubá</cns:tipoCartao>
                    <cns:manual xmlns:cns="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/cadsus/v5r0/cns">canjica</cns:manual>
                    <cns:justificativaManual xmlns:cns="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/cadsus/v5r0/cns" />
                </usu:CNS>
            </usu:Cartoes>
        </usu:UsuarioSUS>
    </cad:responseConsultar>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Meu código:

```
<?php
$x = simplexml_load_file('xml/teste.xml');
echo $x -> Body -> responseConsultar -> UsuarioSUS -> Cartoes -> CNS -> 
numeroCNS;
?>
```

> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object

Se remover **manualmente** os *namespaces*, o código funciona. Mas seria inviável fazer isso em todos os arquivos XML. O que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há uma resposta no [stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485162/simplexml-load-string-will-not-read-soap-response-with-soap-in-the-tags) que fornece uma base para solucionar seu problema. O problema é que a extensão simple load xml, não consegue fazer o parse dos namespaces presentes no seu xml. Isso pode ser contornado com a função [children](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php). Colocando tudo junto fica:

```
<?php
$x = simplexml_load_file('xml/teste.xml');
$campos = $x->children('soap', true)->children('cad', true)->children('usu', true)->UsuarioSUS->Cartoes->CNS->children('cns', true);

foreach($campos as $chave => $valor){
    echo $chave . ' : ' . $valor . '<br>';
}

?>
```

Há um pequeno erro no xml postado na pergunta. Falta colocar no final do arquivo o fechamento `</soap:Envelope>`.

Comment: Funcionou legal! Quanto ao fechamento da tag, devo ter esquecido na hora de copiar o conteúdo do xml. Pois o meu está fechado.